# Find out a package's configure/compile options in Gentoo

Tags: gentoo

On a Gentoo Linux box which I'm not administering (and to which I don't have root access), how can I find out the options which were used to compile the package?

(Please note I've never worked with Gentoo before, but have good working knowledge of Debian-based distros)

Comment: The answer by noisebleed is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the portage package manager is used (it most likely is) then the CPU flags can be found in `/etc/make.conf` as `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. Note that individual ebuilds may filter certain flags, so the flags you see in `/etc/make.conf` may not be the ones that were used to compile the package. Looking at the ebuild (under `/usr/portage/<category name>/<program name>/`) might tell you if that is the case.

This assumes of course that the contents of `/etc/make.conf` weren't changed after the compilation of the package.

Comment: `/etc/make.conf` may not reflect options used when the package was installed. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Please be aware that current USE flags and other configuration defined in `/etc/make.conf` may have changed since the package was installed. A more reliable way of checking configuration and compile options is to check `var/db/pkg`.

Example for apache-2.2.22:

```
$ cat /var/db/pkg/www-servers/apache-2.2.22-r1/CFLAGS
-mtune=native -O2 -pipe -g
```

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that `make.conf` is not reliable at all, to check how a package is compiled. In fact, it is just one of the *supplementary* config files in a whole list.

From the `man make.conf`:

```
USE_ORDER = "env:pkg:conf:defaults:pkginternal:repo:env.d"
Determines the precedence of layers in the incremental stacking of the USE 
variable. Precedence decreases from left to right such that env overrides 
pkg, pkg overrides conf, and so forth.
```

So the priority is handled as:

1. Shell environment when calling emerge
2. Package specific USE setting in /etc/portage/package.use
3. make.conf
4. Defaults from selected profile
5. Defaults set in package `.ebuild` file
6. Distribution defaults
7. Settings defined in /etc/env.d

So basically an USE flags can be set without being mentioned in `make.conf`. Likewise for CFLAGS (although their order of processing is fixed, but it works similar)

Likewise, USE flags can be masked in a profile without any  in the ebuild or any other sources mentioned above. In short, based on config files you can't.

If you want to know the resulting **global** settings currently used by the system, use `emerge --info`. This should give you a massive amount of details. Usually CFLAGS are not very often overridden for a single package,so you can consider that output definitive.

If you want to know the USE flags of a specific package that is installed, you could use `equery u <package>`, provided the *gentoolkit* package is installed.